# Как работать с файлами для хранения данных в Qt не используя qrc?

Tags: android, qt

Появилась задача запихнуть в проект json-файлик, который должен хранить в себе некоторые данные, которые будут перезаписываться самой программой время от времени. Вариант с ресурсами (qrc) не проканал, так как файлы в нем можно открывать только в режиме ReadOnly. А обычные файлы проект с собой на выпуск переносить не хочет, несмотря на то что в pro-файле есть строка

```
DISTFILES += \
    data/test.txt
```

Ситуация усложняется тем, что это программа под android, и куда запихнуть json-файлик с данными я себе просто не представляю.

Comment: Может просто в код запихать, если небольшой? (инклудом) `auto json = " #include "data.json"  "`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian на крайний случай у меня костыль поаккуратнее есть но хотелось бы услышать все варианты решений

Comment: Могу предположить: настройки по умолчанию носить в json файле в ресурсах, при первом запуске сохранить его на диск и после грузить из него и сохранять в него.

Answer (score 0):

Сохрани его в папочку какую-нибудь, стандартные пути можно взять отсюда
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html